# Why was a legitimate answer of mine deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Robert Harvey decided to delete [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713535), and I have no freaking idea why.

None of the FAQ reasons seem to apply. So some sort of an explanation would be nice, as right now I have no idea what the reason might be.

**Update**
The answer has been undeleted, however, I would still very much like to find out why it was deleted in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I honestly don't know how I missed that one.

The moderator dashboard only shows the first 100 characters or so of text, so the excerpt would have looked something like this:

> Yes, it should work just fine.  However, keep in mind that doing a
>   COUNT(primary_key) usually gives better performance.  So your above
>   query would look like `<wall of code ...`

Really looks like a comment/conversation, from that perspective.  Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks for the explaination.

Comment: Eh, it happens.  Remember C++ comment fiasco of 2011? =P